# Add custom web services to Word 2010 via the Research Pane using Java?

Tags: java, web-services, ms-word

I'm trying to add a web service to Word 2010 via the Research Pane.
I've already read the post here:
[Is there a way to add custom web services to Word 2010 via the Research Pane?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6196571)

But I would like to do the same thing using java. I'm not a C# programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eric_carter/archive/2009/04/10/creating-a-research-service-for-word-2007-in-c-with-visual-studio-2008.aspx it seems all you have to do is implement a web service server side.

So you can do that in Java, using https://axis.apache.org/axis/ or alternative.

You might need to fiddle around a bit to overcome any interop issues (Microsoft client talking to Java service), but there shouldn't be any show stoppers.

Comment: Hi Jason,thanks for the link. I've already saw it before but the problem for me is that is difficult to translate the code from C# to Java. I have no knowledge about C#. I have to write 2 different methods: the first one for register the provider, the second one for the query. I've read from this good tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb226691%28v=office.11%29.aspx .